Use custom transfer function instead of Spl Token::transfer
I am creating a new token and gonna list it on some DEX platforms where user can buy my token.
What i want is when a user gonna buy my token from any platform the transfer function should be my custom transfer function where i implement my logic instead of default spl token transfer function ??
Is there a way we can achieve this ?
Thanks for your help.

SPL tokens are always transferred with the transfer function in the SPL Token or Token Extensions program, but you can make your own logic that is invoked on every transfer, and that can cancel the transfer if necessary, using Token Extension program and transfer hooks!

Trying the transfer hook from token extension but end up with create-extra-metas.
